# Generated XML from XSD: value is not facet-valid with respect to pattern

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd, xml-validation

I have geneated an XML from an XSD. IntelliJ IDEA finds no errors if I validate XSD, but generated XML is not valid because one field is not facet-valid with respect to a specified pattern.

This XSD element looks like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://filmrenting.nure.ua/entity/film/"
                xmlns:tns="http://filmrenting.nure.ua/entity/film/"
                xmlns:ent="http://filmrenting.nure.ua/entity/"
                elementFormDefault="qualified">    

     <!-- other elements-->
        <xsd:simpleType name="Duration">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:duration">
                    <xsd:pattern value="[1-9][0-9]{0,2}M"></xsd:pattern>
                </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      <!-- other elements-->
</xsd:schema>
```

And the generated XML looks like that:

```
<film:film id="3" xmlns:film="http://filmrenting.nure.ua/entity/film/">
  <!-- other elements -->
  <film:duration>P1Y2M6DT14H25M13S</film:duration> <!-- not valid -->
</film:film>
```

I checked the pattern and it seems to have no mistakes. Even if I past a correct value to that field afterwards, it's still considered as not-valid.
How to fix it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. How do you generate the XML?

Comment: @JeroenHeier, hi! I choose and XSD file (view its code), then go to 
Tools -> XML Actions... -> Generate XML Document from XSD Schema.

Comment: The XSD does not contain the element declaration for 'duration'. Please can you find the missing line(s) and edit them into your question.

Comment: Generating a string that is both a valid duration, and valid against a given pattern, sounds pretty challenging, even when there are strings that are valid against both, it's not clear how you would go about finding them. I think you're expecting too much of your tools.

Answer (score 0):

Found a mistake in the pattern. To get minutes only, you need to have "PT" at the beginning of it.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Duration">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:duration">
                    <xsd:pattern value="PT[1-9][0-9]{0,2}M"></xsd:pattern>
                </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Though IDEA still generates invalid XMLs, if I edit that field with a value like "PT130M", there will be no errors detected by IDE. Java parsers recognize it too.